# Optimizing search in linux

Tags: linux, grep

I have a huge log file close to 3GB in size.

My task is to generate some reporting based on # of times something is being logged.

I need to find the number of time StringA , StringB , StringC is being called separately.

What I am doing right now is:

```
grep "StringA" server.log | wc -l
grep "StringB" server.log | wc -l
grep "StringC" server.log | wc -l
```

This is a long process and my script takes close to 10 minutes to complete. What I want to know is that whether this can be optimized or not ? Is is possible to run one grep command and find out the number of time StringA, StringB and StringC has been called individually ?

Comment: You can use `grep -c` instead of `wc -l`: `grep -c "StringA" server.log`. `grep` can't report count of individual strings. You can use `awk`: `awk '/StringA/{a++;} /StringB/{b++;} /StringC/{c++;} END{print a, b, c}' server.log`.

Comment: @l3x I was about to write an answer containing exactly what you wrote in this comment, and then I saw this comment... care to make it into an answer?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I was reluctant to post it since OP is looking for a "fast" solution. I wasn't sure if this would fast enough for him. Posted now anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep -c` instead of `wc -l`:

```
grep -c "StringA" server.log
```

`grep` can't report count of individual strings. You can use awk:

```
out=$(awk '/StringA/{a++;} /StringB/{b++;} /StringC/{c++;} END{print a, b, c}' server.log)
```

Then you can extract each count with a simple [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) array:

```
arr=($out)
echo "StringA="${arr[0]}
echo "StringA="${arr[1]}
echo "StringA="${arr[2]}
```

This (`grep` without `wc`) is certainly going to be faster and possibly `awk` solution is also faster. But I haven't measured any.

Comment: I would expect awk to be much faster because it goes through the file just once, and three greps have to go through it three times.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly this approach could be optimized since grep doesn't perform any text indexing. I would use a text indexing engine like one of those from [this review](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/applications/6-of-the-best-desktop-search-tools-for-linux-666158/1) or this [stackexchange QA](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3086/command-line-friendly-full-text-indexing) . Also you may consider using journald from systemd which stores logs in a structured and indexed format so lookups are more effective.

Answer (score 0):

So many `greps` so little time... :-)

According to [David Lyness](https://davidlyness.com/post/the-functional-and-performance-differences-of-sed-awk-and-other-unix-parsing-utilities), a straight `grep` search is about 7 times as fast as an `awk` in large file searches.

If that is the case, the current approach could be optimized by changing `grep` to `fgrep`, but only if the patterns being searched for are *not* regular expressions. `fgrep` is optimized for fixed patterns.

If the number of instances is relatively small compared to the original log file entries, it may be an improvement to use the `egrep` version of `grep` to create a temporary file filled with all three instances:

```
egrep "StringA|StringB|StringC" server.log > tmp.log
grep "StringA" tmp.log | wc -c
grep "StringB" tmp.log | wc -c
grep "StringC" tmp.log | wc -c
```

The `egrep` variant of `grep` allows for a `|` (vertical bar/pipe) character to be used between two or more separate search strings so that you can find multiple strings in statement. You can use `grep -E` to do the same thing.

Full documentation is in the `man grep` page and information about the Extended Regular Expressions that egrep uses from the `man 7 re_format` command.

Comment: These don't show the counts separately, which the OP asks for, though.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, I indeed overlooked the need for the separate counts.  I have revised my answer to remedy that.

Comment: The `awk` in David Lyness' tests is doing more than simply counting regex matches. `grep` is probably a little faster, but I doubt it's 7x faster than the equivalent `awk`.